# Connecting API with zoho creator

Tags: api, zoho, zoho-deluge

I have created the basic form on Zoho creator but I cannot connect with API, I am able to connect with 3rd party API but unable to connect with API, I want to proper step about connect API with Zoho creator also I want to fetch the data from postman

Below I have attached the code:

```
input.Job_Name = input.Job_Name;
url = geturl("https://internal.kiswok.com/empDetailsForZoho/" + input.Job_Name + "empName");
data = Map();
input.Job_Name = url.getJson("empName").getJSON("Job: new_job_name");
//input.Job_Name =  data.get("jobdetails()");
input.Job_Name = data.get("empName");
//input.Job_Name = input.Job_Name;
//url = geturl("https://internal.kiswok.com/empDetailsForZoho" + input.Job_Name + "empName");
//url = geturl("https://internal.kiswok.com/empDetailsForZoho.json?key=" + input.Job_Name + "empName");
//data = Map();
//put.Job_Name = url.getJson("empName").getJSON("empName");
//input.Job_Name = "empName: " + data.get("empName");
// url = geturl("https://internal.kiswok.com/empDetailsForZoho/" + input.Job_Name);
//url = geturl("https://internal.kiswok.com/empDetailsForZoho/");
//fetchchrec = fetchurl.toJSONList();
//data = Map();
//input.Job_Name = " " + data.get("empName");
```

It will be shown the fetching data from site or postman.

I am also attaching screenshots of some errors that I am getting.

The information I am trying to get as the output:

[image: img1]

The information that I am getting right now:

[image: img2]

Please let me know if further information is needed.

Comment: Can you include the third party API details in the question?  i.e What is the Endpoint, Query Parameters and Headers and expected response.

In your screenshot, I can only see the End point and sample response

Endpoint: https://internal.kiswok.com/empDetailsForZoho
Response:   {"empName":"Sam", "id":1}

But your script doing more than this like append input.JobName, etc. Need clarification in your question.

Answer (score 0):

The error may be caused by the initial line in the code:
`input.Job_Name = input.Job_Name;`

Try removing it and re-running the example to see if your script gets further or to a new error?

Example code:

```
if (input.Job_Name != null)
{
url = geturl("https://internal.kiswok.com/empDetailsForZoho/" + input.Job_Name + "empName");
data = Map();
input.Job_Name = url.getJson("empName").getJSON("Job: new_job_name");
...
// Temporary line: Visually verify that Job_Name has the expected value.
info "Job_Name: " + input.Job_Name;
}
```

Comment: input.Job_Name = invokeurl
[
 url :"http://192.168.201.13/"
 type :GET
];
data = Map();
input.Job_Name = " " + data.get("empName");

Right now I am using this script but still I am getting the error, it will not fetch the data giving the null output.

Comment: `input.Job_Name = " " ` looks like it is removing the content from input.Job_Name. It is worth a try to remove it and re-run the script.